# Как вывести данные из модуля crawler?

Tags: node.js, javascript, функции

Модулем [node-crawler](https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler) получаю метаданные , но мугу ими воспользоватса только внутри фунции - вывести в **console.log()** напр.

```
var Crawler = require("crawler").Crawler;
var crawler = new Crawler({"maxConnections":10});
function metadata() {
  crawler.queue([{
  "uri": 'https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler',
  "callback":function(error,result,$) {
    $('meta[property="og:title"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("content"));  });
    $('meta[property="og:description"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("content"));  });
  }}])
 };
metadata()
```

А как мне их вывести вне функции, как создать из них объект с свойствами?

```
var title = $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr("content");
var descr = $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr("content");
```

присвоил переменные, но не работает

Comment: спасибо, все работает. а как вытянуть из массива 
var smth = $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).text(); });
???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Процесс получения мета данных ассинхроных, так что только так: http://jsfiddle.net/7rdJf/